# Should I use Effective M on 9-Max Tournaments?

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, poker-theory, blinds, sit-and-go

In Tourneys I'm using Harrington [M-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ratio) to determine actions and opponent ranges.

My question is should I use [Effective M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ratio#Effective_M) with 9-Max full ring tables (using a 9/10 factor), or I should just use raw M instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using raw M is the way to go. Like it says in the wikipedia article that you linked, it is assuming that 10 is a full table. if you are playing 9-max, 9 would be a full table instead of 10. In the equation you would replace the 10 with a 9, and assuming that every seat at the 9 handed table is full, you will be using the raw M.

Comment: Thanks, ultimately I did the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use effective M if I am the biggest stack on the table by a big margin. If I am 100BB deep but the second largest stack who hasn't folded is 20BB, I must play a 20BB-ish strategy